# How can I clear the MonkeyRunner application cache?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I need to run a test suite using monkeyrunner. Is there a way to clear the app cache after running some tests other than `monkey.device.uninstall()`?

Answer (score 0):

to clear your cache use the following line of code.

```
File dir = context.getCacheDir(); 
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) { 
     deleteDir(dir); 
    } 


    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) { 
     if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) 
     { 
       String[] children = dir.list(); 
       for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { 
        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i])); 
        if (!success) { 
         return false; 
        } 
       } 
     } 
    return dir.delete(); 
   }
```

for more detail http://grabcodes.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb command to remove the cache folder of app like below.
You should know the folder path for that app.
For facebook app,

```
adb shell
cd /Android/data/com.facebook.katakana/cache
rm *
exit
```

This clears the cache. If your using monkeyrunner then from jython code you can use

```
subprocess.call("<above mentioned commands>")
```